# Merge pdf comments into single file

Tags: linux, pdf

I have two pdf files, which are copies of the same document. But one has comments and highlights that the other does not have. I want to merge all the comments into the same document.

Adobe Acrobat has this function (Comments -> Import comments). Is there a way to do this under Linux?

Comment: answered before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη That is different. This one is about comments.

Comment: I doubt that could be done outside adobe acrobat, did you try to install it over `wine`?

Comment: @jimmij I always have trouble with `wine`. It doesn't seem to support the latest version of adobe acrobat very well. Has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now PDF Studio Pro (https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudio/) and Master PDF Editor (https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/) have this feature.

PDF Studio Pro is very convenient because you can import a PDF's comments directly into another. But the Pro version (which has this feature) is commercial.

Master PDF Editor offers a free version that has this feature. But you have to export a .fdf file containing comments from one of the PDF files, and then import this .fdf file from the other PDF. I hope someday they let you import comments directly from one PDF to another.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem: two scans of the same document, created with an non-duplex scanner, meaning document *odd.pdf* with the odd pages and *even.pdf* with the even pages.

To merge this two documents page by page I've used the `pdftk` command with the `shuffle` option:

```
pdftk A=odd.pdf B=even.pdf shuffle A B output merged.pdf
```